# Color Individual Variables With Javascript & PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

What am I doing wrong?

```
} else {
    $output = '<script type="text/javascript">jAlert("<font color="red">'$number1'</font>", "Alert Dialog Sample")</script>';
}
```

I am getting:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Comment: You're thinking that `<font color="red">'$number1'</font>` is a valid code, though it is not

Comment: Ok well thats why I am here. I am trying to think of a way to "style" PHP variables in java-script

Comment: Here have a few dots: `..........` <- use these. Seriously though, there are many free editors which would highlight that invalid syntax right away.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the dots around $number1 which is used for concatenation

```
    $output = '<script type="text/javascript">jAlert("<font color="red">'.$number1.'</font>", "Alert Dialog Sample")</script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be like this

```
$output = '<script type="text/javascript">jAlert("<font color="red">'.$number1.'</font>", "Alert Dialog Sample")</script>';
```

}

Comment: Although that takes away the errors, my box is no longer popping up

Comment: I have already tried all those codes that you guys are saying. They dont produce any errors but they "disable" my javascript code from running.

Comment: it should be `alert` i guess. not jAlert. unless you have a function named `jAlert`

Comment: that is correct, its a function called jAlert. If I remove <font then it works fine. I need to color the variables though?

Comment: well are you using `alert` popup?

Comment: No. Like I said, if <font comes out and I just use $number1, it will work fine. But then it wont be styled anymore, and that is my main goal here.

Comment: Yes i understand, but whats in your `jAlert` function? how do you output `<font color="red">'.$number1.'</font>` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the string concatenation operator.

```
} else {
    $output = '<script type="text/javascript">jAlert("<font color="red">' . $number1 . '</font>", "Alert Dialog Sample")</script>';
}
```

I would refrain from using the font tag though as it is deprecated.